# Django switch between inlines in the admin

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a multi-role user login module for my Django project. I currently have two roles How can I change the inlines showing on the admin page according to the role choice?

```
#models.py in users
class User(AbstractUser):

role_choice = (
        ('Reader', u'Reader'),
        ('Author', u'Author'),
        ('Editor', u'Editor'),
        ('Admin', u'Admin')
    )
    user_role = models.CharField(choices=role_choice,
                                 max_length=150,
                                 default='Admin',
                                 verbose_name='Role')
#admin.py in users
class ReaderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Reader
    extra = 2
class AuthorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Author
    extra = 2
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm
    inlines = [ReaderInline, AuthorInline]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the inline objects creation with `ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances

```py
class UserAdmin:
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj.role == 'Reader':
            return ReaderInline(self.model, self.admin_site)
        else:
             ... You got it
```

Comment: Hi @louis saglio, Thanks for the reply, I tried your way and it is returning me an error saying NoneType is do not have 'user_role'